# The Win32 internal error "A device attached to the system is not functioning" 0x1F occurred while setting 2 the console window title

Tags: windows, powershell, tfs

I have a PowerShell script that get a response from an API:

```
$test = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType application/json -UseDefaultCredentials
```

Then, iterate the response with `foreach`:

```
$test.value | foreach {
  # Do something
}
```

In my PC it works great, but I want it will run automatically so I created a TFS build definition and it runs in our build servers.

During the build I get the following error in the middle of the `foreach`:

```
foreach : The Win32 internal error "A device attached to the system is not functioning" 0x1F occurred while setting 
the console window title. Contact Microsoft Customer Support Services.
At D:\AGT\Test\01\_temp\test.ps1:9 char:17
+ $builds.value | foreach {
+                 ~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [ForEach-Object], HostException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetConsoleWindowTitle,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand
```

If I have log-in to the server and run the script, it works. only during the TFS build it doesn't work.

I googled it a lot but couldn't solve it. any idea?

Comment: might want to look into the HostException no?

Comment: What is the meaning of the `HostException`?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.host.hostexception?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0  
I'm guessing $builds doesn't contain what you think it does

Comment: @JJF the `$build` it the `$test` - the API response, I updated the code. in my PC it works great, in our servers it doesn't. BTW - the response it's over 5000 values.

Comment: I really don't know much at all about PS so maybe I can't help.  Seems to me $build.value is piping something into foreach that it does not like.  I'd say printf out what you're piping to foreach.  But like I said maybe I can't help.  Good luck.

Comment: Can you elaborate on `# Do something`?  Are you copying, moving, compressing, or decompressing files in your `foreach` loop?  If so, is your anti-virus scanner paused or configured to exclude the files you are working with?  If you are using virtual network attached storage on your servers, you may want to explore copying just the file data; not ownership, ACLs, or file attributes.  Sometimes flaky device drivers, network buffering, indexing options, file system corruption, etc. can cause these types of issues (esp. for removable devices, such as USB or backup drives).

Comment: @leeharvey1 I have another `Invoke-RestMethod` method and `New-Item` to put the JSON results in a new file.

Comment: More info - I logged-in to the server and run the script there without issues. only in the TFS build, it failed with the error.

Comment: Maybe it's related to pipe (|) handling, and/or the use of the `foreach` alias that calls `ForEach-Object`.  Can you try changing your `$test.value | foreach {` to `foreach ($testValue in $test.value) {` then use `$testValue` instead of `$_` when you `# Do something` inside the loop?  This should force usage of the `foreach` statement, rather than the alias.

Comment: @leeharvey1 thank you, I tried it but I got the same error :(

Comment: Final thoughts: Login as the account context used for your TFS project builds, then sanity check %PATH% environment variable, and the permissions of your %TEMP% and %TMP% folders.  It might be profile-related.

Comment: @leeharvey1 thanks but I know which command causes the issue. I perform in the “foreach” 'git add' & 'git commit' in each iteration of the loop.
When I took them out of the loop and perform it only one time in the end I don’t get the error.
I still don't know why it only failed in the build but at least I have a workaround.